# Command > Rich Model > Event pattern in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC app attempting to avoid the [Fat Controller](http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2008/12/03/the-fat-controller/) smell. I am doing this by making controller methods simply send lightweight commands to a command bus, which then get picked up by command handlers. The command handlers enact the commands on the domain model, which in turn creates state-change events that are persisted.

I am doing this to try and get away from the CRUD model of "get X from repository, change it and put it back", remove all domain-specific knowledge from the web application and to allow the intent of the user to be communicated directly to the domain model.

So, let's say a Contact aggregate is composed as follows (I have omitted all but one of the setter methods for brevity).

```
public class Contact {

    private Address _homeAddress;

    public Address HomeAddress { 
        get { return _homeAddress; }
        set {
            if(newHomeAddress.Equals(_homeAddress)) return;
            _homeAddress = newHomeAddress;
            AddEvent(new HomeAddressChanged(Id, _homeAddress));
        }
    }

    public Address WorkAddress { get; set; }

    public PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public EmailAddress EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The command handler that enacts a change of HomeAddress would look like so.

```
public class ChangeHomeAddressCommandHandler : IHandleCommand<ChangeHomeAddressCommand>
{
    private IRepository<Contact> _repo;

    public ChangeHomeAddressCommandHandler(IRepository<Contact> repo) 
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public void Execute(ChangeHomeAddressCommand command)
    {
        var toEdit = _repo.One(command.Id);
        toEdit.HomeAddress = command.NewHomeAddress;
        _repo.CommitChanges(toEdit);
    }
}
```

My trouble is that the form that the user submits needs to allow editing of a WHOLE CONTACT i.e. all of its associated addresses, phone numbers &c) which means that there needs to be a command and a handler for each and every property state change.

Each one of these handlers needs to load the aggregate, make the changes and then commit the changes. So even if you don't change all the properties, the command handler still has to load and build the Contact aggregate four times, which is unnecessarily expensive.

I have considered some options...

1. A "macro" command (called maybe EditContactCommand) into which instances of each possible sub-command (i.e. the individual ChangeHomeAddressCommand) can be added. The macro command loads the aggregate and passes it through the sub-commands and commits changes on dispose.
2. Making the UI more "task focussed". Instead of the Edit page being a structured collection of textboxes to gather input, use labels accompanied by a "Change" button which invokes a modal dialog. When the modal dialog is OK'd, make an AJAX post back to the controller which in turns buses a command. Or indeed, build smaller pages which only expose certain facets of the Contact aggregate. You only ever change what has actually changed, and changes can happen without a big "Save"-style commit. (I'm not sure whether the users would wear this because they seem to like their sea of textboxes!)

I'd be grateful for any advice, experience and wisdom. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you're trying hard to un-CRUDify an application that is (as far as we can tell from that little code) very CRUDish in nature.

No matter how you try to bend your commands to make them look less like CRUD, they won't make any sense if they don't describe a domain reality -- it only adds more unnecessary complexity. Changing an email address might be a command of its own right if it triggers a whole process of re-sending a validation email and so on, but not if it just modifies the email field.

I think there's nothing wrong with commands that modify an entire entity, as long as they are valid domain operations/events explored with your domain expert and there's not 100% of them. Applications are rarely purely CRUD, but when they are, DDD is certainly not the best approach to choose.

Comment: Thanks. That's a useful observation and without the domain context I agree it's hard to arbitrate. Suffice it to say that there certainly are realities of my domain that make more sense as commands than observing simple CRUD state changes and as the requirements emerge I want to ensure that I don't "paint myself into a corner" - if the user suddenly decides they need to do something when a phone number changes, for instance, it'll be easier if these intents are already separated. Or at least that's what I am telling myself!

Comment: Between guaranteed complexity/head scratching now and hypothetically having to split a command into multiple ones later, I'd go for the latter any day. But maybe it's just me, and I'm not in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You might be already painting yourself in a corner. I'm missing the user's intent. Why is the home address being changed? Did the user make a typo or did the contact really move? If it's the latter, you might need to send an email - if it's the former, probably not.

Let scenario's drive you to discovering the user's intent.